# Mixture of Binomials: Penalization

Tags: binomial-distribution, model-selection, bic

I have a set of data points generated from 2 random variables:

1st: with prior probability 1 the point was generated by Binomial with 0.5 success probability.

2nd: with priors 0.5 and 0.5 the point was generated by two Binomials with 0.4 and 0.6 probabilities of success (so we have a mixture).

The problem is: the 2nd model can be preferable just because it has more parameters. If I would estimate scales/locations/mixture proportions, I would just use BIC for penalization for number of parameters. But here I estimate nothing, all the parameters are "hard coded". How can I penalize the more complicated model in this case?

ANSWER: No, you can not penalise your data if you estimated nothing because there are no fitting => no *overfitting*. 2nd model is preferable in case additional factors were not taken into account (for example, if your 1st model does not describe reality well so you can see "outliers" - points that have extra small likelihood). No estimation => no penalisation.